# AngularJS failed to instantiate module

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-module

Im new in AngularJS and im trying to create an authentication service but I'm getting this error.

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module flujoDeCaja due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module auth due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'auth' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Here is my code:

**Service.js**

```
'use strict';

var mod = angular.module('auth',['restangular']);

mod.service('AuthService', ['', function(){

    var userIsAuthenticated = false;

    this.setUserAuthenticated = function(value){
        userIsAuthenticated = value;
    };

    this.getUserAuthenticated = function(){
        return userIsAuthenticated;
    });

}]);
```

**App.js**

```
var angularModule = angular.module('flujoDeCaja', [
  'ngCookies',
  'ngResource',
  'ngSanitize',
  'ngRoute',
  'restangular',
  'auth'
]);
```

**Index.html**

```
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/restangular/dist/restangular.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/services/services.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: don't need a blank string for the dependencies if you have none for the service definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrected the bit I believe is wrong.

```
mod.service('AuthService', [function(){

    var userIsAuthenticated = false;

    this.setUserAuthenticated = function(value){
        userIsAuthenticated = value;
    };

    this.getUserAuthenticated = function(){
        return userIsAuthenticated;
    };

}]);
```

Comment: Thank you, you are right. My other mistake was that ')' after getUserAuthenticated function's '}'

Comment: cool thanks for the feedback, updated my answer to reflect the changes needed to fix it all